# pstack not printing stack output

Tags: stack-trace, printstacktrace, pstack

I am running pstack to find function stack for my application running on two machines (both RHEL)

In one of my machine it is working as expected

```
[root@civ4cez191 bin]# pstack 22947
Thread 2 (Thread 0x7f63cbe7d700 (LWP 22949)):
#0  0x0000003c3640f0cd in pause () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x0000000000485a78 in _signalWaitThread(void*) ()
#2  0x0000003c36407aa1 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x0000003c360e8aad in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Thread 1 (Thread 0x7f63d2d07700 (LWP 22947)):
#0  0x0000003c360e1523 in select () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00000000004ccc36 in TFDSETSelect(void*, void*, int) ()
#2  0x00000000004cb50f in SvrInit1(unsigned int (*)(void*, void**), unsigned int (*)(void*, void*, void**, unsigned int*), void (*)(void*), unsigned int (*)(unsigned short, unsigned short), void (*)(unsigned short, unsigned short), void (*)(unsigned short, unsigned short), unsigned short, unsigned char, unsigned short, unsigned char) ()
#3  0x00000000004259f0 in main ()
```

However in other machine it is just printing name of the threads

```
[root@civ4cez194 bin]# pstack 12672
Thread 7 (Thread 0x7f01892e2700 (LWP 12674)):
Thread 6 (Thread 0x7f0188aa0700 (LWP 12743)):
Thread 5 (Thread 0x7f0188a1e700 (LWP 7090)):
Thread 4 (Thread 0x7f0188a5f700 (LWP 7127)):
Thread 3 (Thread 0x7f01889dd700 (LWP 7178)):
Thread 2 (Thread 0x7f0188ae1700 (LWP 7235)):
Thread 1 (Thread 0x7f0193ca0740 (LWP 12672)):
```

I have looked for a way to resolve this but haven't had much success. 
Only significant information I found was [here](http://gnu.wiki/man1/pstack.1.php)

> For thread information to  be  dumped,  you  have  to  use  the 
>   debug-aware  version  of  the LinuxThreads  libpthread.so  library.
>   (To  check,  run  nm(1) on your       pthreads    library,    and
>   make    sure     that     the     symbol "__pthread_threads_debug"  is
>   defined.)  Threads are not supported with the newer NPTL libpthread.so
>   library.

On doing nm on /lib64/libpthread.so.0 on both the machines, I find "__pthread_debug" for both.

Will appreciate help.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out there was issue with python installation on the setup due to which backtrace was not working, fixing python installation fixed the problem.